# Expert opinion needed on Database design

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, storage-engines

I would appreciate advice from experts on a Database schema for a website.

I have  a database design for a classifieds listings site that is currently done in MyISAM engine so there are no relationships, keys etc.

Please have a look at the ER Model for the current design:

[image]

[image]

I need to know if i'm on the right track with  the DB Design... (The Email and Password fields are redundant in both Users and Ads tables since the first plan was  not to require user registration but that plan was changed lately.  So, please ignore this bit since i'll remove these fields from Ads table)

It's expected that the site has the potential to do  at least a minimum of 100,000 page views a day  within a few months from launch.

Please advice about what do you think about this design and what could be done better.

Also please advice on the best Db Engine to use for such a site(InnoDb or any other...).

Please advice on what would be the best storage engine for this database  keeping in mind the Performance, Load , Db Integrity(if needed since it's designed on MyISAM engine currently and hence no Db integrity) and whatever else there is to consider for such a site.

I know specific database issues/problems can only be handled only when they occur in reality, but at least i want to make a start in  the right direction.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: what's the difference between ipn and payment?

Comment: The first thing that catches my attention: there are no FK relationships in that ER model

Comment: You might want to consider normalization, if you haven't done so already. Looking at Users, for instance, I wonder whether you really want multiple users to share the same email, password, etc., or if users can have both confirmed AND forgotten to confirm their registration. Redundancies like this can lead to inconsistencies or require complicated integrity checks...

Comment: @ Andrew Cooke - Just consider ipn

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name - Yes no FK relationships since it uses  MyISAM storage Engine

Comment: @ Patrick87 - I don't understand what you're trying to say... User Table has a id field(primary key) email and passwords would be unique... confirm and forgot_confirm are for registration link codes whether cnfirmed or need to resend ... what redundancy are you talking about?

Comment: Why down vote my question...  i'm here to seek an answer for something i don't consider myself knowledgeable about ... if i was an expert on the topic i wouldn't be seeking help from you people :)

Comment: Please consider me an end user for this database design since i did only a few modifications that were needed to add a few features.

Comment: I don't know about others but for me the images are displayed as broken.

Comment: @TigOldBitties: Images break randomly for me, too. I usually just wait a few hours. Then the problem seems to go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why oh why would you use MyISAM? From what I see, you're not talking about a high performance website, so why use it??? Go with InnoDB.
2. Data integrity is not an option, so if you're not an expert you probably didn't think about implementing logic for it in your application so you should really consider using FK.
3. Only looking at your ER model (which is not even an ERM since you have no relationships defined so there is no R, it's more of a EM) we can't say all that much. We need a story, and the story seems big.
4. 100k hits a day is peanuts and in this case misleading. What's the highest expected rate per second? For how long must it be possible to sustain this level?
5. This model is also missing the data types. Those are not optional for even a minimal analyzes.
6. Something like this usually takes days to discuss and analyze, I find it a bit over the edge over here, especially given the scarcity of information.

Comment: Thanks Marius. I'm not too sure about if the data Integrity is implemented inside application logic since i haven't had a look at all of the code.  Whatever i've seen of it doesn't seem to suggest anything like this.  What are the chances that i break up the code if i add Foreign keys to the database now?  I guess there won't be any instances in code  where some data is being manipulated without checking it's validity/integrity but what happens if there is any such instance and i add foreign keys...how do i manage this situation if it really does occur?

Comment: And as for the EM, i just used a free basic modelling tool on a MYISAm(hence no FK's etc.) db.

Comment: You might indeed encounter problems if you add FKs to your tables and the application is not programmed right. For instance you insert into `adpics` before inserting the ad you create the pic for into `ads`. Without the error, an invalid entry would be inserted into `adpics`(invalid because the referred ad doesn't exist). My suggestion is to do the change, test and fix any problems which you encounter. The problems are not new, you just discover them with the help of FK instead of getting your data corrupted (entries referencing other entries that don't exist).

Answer (score 2):

At a glance . . .

We can't see primary keys, unique constraints, or anything like that in your diagram. Their absence is troubling.

Almost every table has an id number. Several of them are just called "id", and others have a more descriptive name. *More descriptive* is the better of those two ideas.

An id number in a table that has no other unique constraints is usually a mistake. (Usually, but not always.) For example, the table "cats" probably needs a unique constraint on "catname". Otherwise, the id number will only identify a row, not a cat. (And that means you can have two or more rows with the same "catname".)

The tables adxfields and subcatxfields look like a disaster waiting on opportunity. The table 'subcatxfields' looks like some kind of EAV anti-pattern. Look carefully at [Bill Karwin's slideshow on database anti-patterns](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) before you go down that road. (EAV starts on slide 16.)

Subcat pricing should probably be moved to a separate table.

There's an [international standard for country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists.htm). You're better off using the standard country codes instead of your own id number. Using a human-readable code means you can usually eliminate a join. (Usually, but not always.)

The table "cities" doesn't have enough columns to identify a city. (There are lots of cities named "Washington" in the USA.)

That's enough time . . .

Comment: Thanks Catcall. The intent to use keys, Constraints is there even though it doesn't show up in the Entity Model since it's a MYISAM engine... What improvements do you suggest for adxfields subcatfields?